# How to get the EXIF metadata info from a base64 image in Ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native

I am picking an image from android phone gallery using Ionic native Camera plugin which is giving me base64 data which is my requirement for the time. Now, on some mobiles the image picked (base64 data) returns with its orientation rotated. How can I can extract the EXIF information from this base64 image and change its orientation so that I can then send it to the server for uploading.
and I am not looking for the upload code. Just the EXIF info & change orientation part.

Any help is highly appreciated in advance :).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cordova-plugin-camera-with-exif](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-camera-with-exif) library to get the **EXIF** metadata

Comment: I couldn't install it. It threw an error that says 'failed version requirement is android<6.x.x and I have 7.x.x'

Answer (score 0):

I have used [piexifjs](http://piexifjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to read the Exif data and add geo coordinates to a  base64. I bet you can fix the orientation issue using the same plugin. But the plugin itself very memory intensive. It took more than 2 minutes to read the exif data, change, and write again to a base64.